# plpgsql: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql

I've created a function in PostgreSQL using DBeaver.
& I'm trying to insert data into table by calling the function from DBeaver. But it's giving me an error:

> SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function public.proc_insert_test(integer, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, timestamp with time zone, integer, integer, integer, timestamp with time zone) does not exist
> Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
> Position: 8

Function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.proc_insert_test(
  p_brndcode integer, p_brndname varchar(100), p_brndsname varchar(100), 
  p_prdtype char(1), p_discontinue char(1), p_crddate date,
  p_status integer, p_recstat integer, p_brndgrpseqno integer,
p_wefrom date)
RETURNS char 
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $body$
BEGIN
  Insert into arc_mmstbrndgroup(brndcode, brndname, brndsname, prdtype, discontinue, crddate, status, recstat, brndgrpseqno, wefrom) 
  values(p_brndcode, p_brndname, p_brndsname, p_prdtype, p_discontinue, p_crddate, p_status, p_recstat, p_brndgrpseqno, p_wefrom);
END;
$body$
;
```

Calling the function:

```sql
select public.proc_insert_test(123, 'Test2', 'Test2', 'T', 'T', now(), 1, 9, 1234, now());
```

What can be the issue?

I'm totally new to this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Postgres doesn't allow implicit conversion from `timestamp` to `date` data type. Attention - Postgres `date` type is different from Oracle's `date` type.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test(v date)
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
 AS $function$
 BEGIN
   RAISE NOTICE '%', v;
 END;
 $function$

postgres=# SELECT test(now());
ERROR:  function test(timestamp with time zone) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT test(now());
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
postgres=# SELECT test(current_date);
NOTICE:  2019-11-14
+------+
| test |
+------+
|      |
+------+
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT test(now()::date);
NOTICE:  2019-11-14
+------+
| test |
+------+
|      |
+------+
(1 row)
```

The conversion from `timestamp` (result type of `now()` function) to `date` is losing conversions. It is not allowed by default. So you should to enforce it (by explicit casting), or you should to use pseudo constant `current_date` that returns `date` type, and there is not necessary any conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I created the [PL/pgSQL function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) with an `OUT` parameter as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(OUT value INTEGER) AS $$
BEGIN                 -- ↑ Here
SELECT 2 + value INTO value;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, calling `my_func(3)` got the same error as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func(3);
ERROR:  function my_func(integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT my_func(3);
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

So, I used an `INOUT` parameter as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(INOUT value INTEGER) AS $$
BEGIN                  -- ↑ Here
SELECT 2 + value INTO value;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, I could call `my_func(3)` without error as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func(3);
 my_func
---------
       5
(1 row)
```